# Active input text only after check the checkbox

Tags: jquery

I would like to have some checkboxes and same number of input type text. But i would like to have active only some text field. Im using jquery validation plugin. I saw at official documentation that should be working some of like: require:"#checkboxid:check" but for me isnt working.

Can anybody help me please?

Live: http://marygate.cz/aaaa/

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: id must be unique.Your all text-boxes have id `aaa`.Use class `aaa` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the is(':checked') + click() jquery function to do that

```
$("#checkbox1").click( function(){`   
   if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
      $("#inputentry1").removeAttr("disabled");
   }else{
      $("#inputentry1").attr("disabled",true);
   }
});
```

Comment: great, thanks, i thought it could be done by validation plugin but this works too, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

A little hard to tell what you're asking, but I believe you want a textbox that is only active when the associated checkbox is checked.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox"/><input type="text" disabled/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    $(this).next(":text").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/GFzWU/